# How to resize Panel (wxPython) after adding to BoxSizer

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I want to make a "mouse over" effect on some panels...

When the mouse is over, I want to increase the size of the panel and when mouse leaves, the panel goes back to the original size.

I was able to change size but the Box Sizer will not move, so, the max size is limited to the original, and if I decrease I can see the Frame behind it. I tried to use Layout/Refresh/Update not only in the panel but also in the Box Sizer but none worked...

Any hint?